# Incorrect number of theta components (!1)

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to do a generalized linear mixed model and after all return a message the I have an incorrect number of theta.

I'm trying to run a generalized linear mixed model and my variables are:

```
   fr fc          ed np      nnd ID_site RN_total_effort
4  15 34 0.006209597 13 748.4804      13            1344
9  13 81 0.004367510  3 306.6037      22             680
10 10 80 0.006039674  3 106.2123      25             680
11 15 50 0.011958544 13 792.4102      31             680
12 12 36 0.008262562 13 867.6111      35             680
13 16 75 0.006942968  4 686.7576      36             680
```

`fr` is my answer and (`fc`, `ed`, `np` and `nnd`) are my explanatory variables. I'am using GLMER and `ID_site` is my random factor. Also I have studies that has different effort `RN_total_effort`, so I pondered my model using offset. Here is my code.

```
m1_mist<-glmer(fr~fc+nnd+ed+np+(1|ID_site), offset(mist$RN_total_effort), family= poisson, data=mist)
```

After run gives this message:

```
Error in glmer(fr ~ fc + nnd + ed + np + (1 | ID_site), offset(mist$RN_total_effort),  : 
  'control' is not a list; use glmerControl()
```

I use this:

```
m1_mist<-glmer(fr~fc+nnd+ed+np+(1|ID_site), offset(mist$RN_total_effort), family= poisson, data=mist, control=glmerControl(optimizer="nloptwrap", optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)))
```

And returns this:

```
Error in getStart(start, lower = rho$lower, pred = rho$pp, "theta") : 
  incorrect number of theta components (!=1)
Além disso: Warning message:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

I rescaled the variables (`ed` and `nnd`) and run again:

```
m1_mist<-glmer(fr~fc+nndr+edr+np+(1|ID_site), offset(mist$RN_total_effort), family= poisson, data=mist, control=glmerControl(optimizer="nloptwrap", optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)))
```

And appear this message now:

```
Error in getStart(start, lower = rho$lower, pred = rho$pp, "theta") : 
  incorrect number of theta components (!=1)
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages appear because the offset variable is provided as a positional argument, not as a named one. In the examples, it was whether at the position of the `control=` or `start=` arguments. 
To avoid such mistakes, just use the names explicitly, while providing the arguments, i.e.

`glmer(..., offset = mist$RN_total_effort)`.

Alternatively, you may include the offset into the formula as

`fr ~ fc+nndr+edr+np+(1|ID_site) + offset(RN_total_effort)`.